# HttpClient Image file is not is not fully downloaded c#

Tags: c#, download, httpclient

I have this code :

```
for(int i = 0; i< Alim(exo).Count; i++)
             {
                APIResource a = new APIResource();
                a = Alim(exo)[i];
              
                object test;
                if (!_cache.TryGetValue(a.name, out test))
                {
                    
                    _cache.Set(a.name, a.name);
                  
                    //System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(2000);
                    using (var httpClient = new HttpClient())
                    {
                        using (var request = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Get, Alim(exo)[i].url))
                        {
                            using (
                                Stream contentStream = await (await httpClient.SendAsync(request)).Content.ReadAsStreamAsync(),
                                stream = new FileStream(Path.Combine(specificFolder, Alim(exo)[i].name), FileMode.Create, FileAccess.ReadWrite))
                            {
                                await contentStream.CopyToAsync(stream);
                                
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    MessageBox.Show("coucou");
                    
                }
                exo[i].ThumbnailLocalPath = @"secretpath" + a.name;
             }
```

But my images are not fully donwloaded look at screenshot :

[image]
[image]

To make it Work i have to put the `thread.sleep.`

I also tried with `Webclient.DownloadFile`

My function is `Async.`

Thanks you.

Comment: Most likely the response from `await httpClient.SendAsync(request)` contains more info. Perhaps you're being rate limited, or requesting an URL that doesn't return an image, or, or, or. Save the content in a separate variable and inspect its response headers and body. If you open the non-image file in a text editor like Notepad++, that'll probably teach you something as well.

Comment: on notepad : `<html>
<head><title>429 Too Many Requests</title></head>
<body>
<center><h1>429 Too Many Requests</h1></center>
<hr><center>openresty</center>
</body>
</html>`

Comment: So apparently you're being throttled. You will have to slow down your requests, and you should check the API you're talking to in order to learn about the limits you have to follow.

Comment: It's also good practice to check the status code of the response, e.g. with `response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode()`

Comment: @canton7 `EnsureSuccessStatusCode()` throws, you'd rather use the bool `IsSuccessStatusCode` as you don't want exceptions for control flow.

Comment: No, but you want an exception for a case you're not handling. OP's code currently doesn't handle anything, so throwing is appropriate. Handle the status codes you know how to handle, throw for the rest

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> `<html> <head><title>429 Too Many Requests</title></head> <body> <center><h1>429 Too Many Requests</h1></center> <hr><center>openresty</center> </body> </html>`

So a 429 is exactly what I was [talking about](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65089168/httpclient-image-file-is-not-is-not-fully-downloaded-c-sharp?noredirect=1#comment115071507_65089168), you're issuing too many requests in too short of a timespan, according to their server's configuration and response.

If they're generous, they include a `Retry-After` response header. Otherwise you'll have to retry (preferably with an [exponential backoff](https://cloud.google.com/iot/docs/how-tos/exponential-backoff), i.e. 1.x, 2.x, 4.x, ... seconds where x is a random number of milliseconds) until you succeed.

In order to do this, you should start by saving and inspecting the response:

```
var response = await httpClient.SendAsync(request);
if (!response.IsSuccessStatusCode)
{
    // wait, then retry
}
```

And also, don't dispose HttpClient, reuse it for your application lifetime.

Comment: Also worth noting perhaps that the OP's code contains a race, where two threads might check the cache, decide there's no entry, and both issue simultaneous requests for the image, which might hit the rate limit. It's also worth fixing that cache race condition.

Comment: I don't see threading issues in the presented code, nor proof that OP runs this code on multiple threads, but yeah, that too could be a problem if so.

Comment: (Also, on .NET Core 2.1+, when `SocketsHttpHandler` was introduced, disposing HttpClient makes no difference I believe -- the issues which affected the older `HttpClientHandler` were fixed)

Comment: _"HttpClient is intended to be instantiated once and re-used throughout the life of an application. Instantiating an HttpClient class for every request will exhaust the number of sockets available under heavy loads. This will result in SocketException errors."_ is still in the docs of .Net 5' HttpClient @canton7 Or did you mean something else?